# How to generate ctags for google protobuf

Tags: indexing, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, ctags, cscope

My source code has some protobuf files like common.proto.

It looks like ctags doesn't generate tags for the messages. How do I generate the tags for the messages so that I can search for the fields present in the messages.

Answer (score 3):

Universal-ctags (https://ctags.io) supports protobuf.

```
$ cat input.proto
package TestPackage;

message Message1 {
    required string field1 = 1 [default="; required string thisIsNotAField = 1;"];
    //optional string commentedField2 = 2;
    /* optional string commentedField3 = 3; */
}

message Message2 {
    message NestedMessage {
        required string field2 = 2;
    }

    enum Enum1 {
        YES = 1;
        NO = 2;
    }

    repeated NestedMessage field3 = 3;
    optional Enum1 field4 = 4;
}

message Message3 {
    required Message2.NestedMessage field5 = 5;
    required .TestPackage.Message2.Enum1 field6 = 6;

    extensions 7 to 8;
}

extend Message3 {
    optional Message2 . NestedMessage field7 = 7;
    repeated int32 field8 = 8 [packed=true];
}

service Service1 {
    rpc Method1(Message1) returns(Message2);
}

$ ./ctags -o - input.proto
Enum1   Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    enum Enum1 {$/;"  g
Message1    Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^message Message1 {$/;"    m
Message2    Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^message Message2 {$/;"    m
Message3    Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^message Message3 {$/;"    m
NO  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^        NO = 2;$/;"   e
NestedMessage   Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    message NestedMessage {$/;"   m
Service1    Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^service Service1 {$/;"    s
TestPackage Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^package TestPackage;$/;"  p
YES Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^        YES = 1;$/;"  e
field1  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    required string field1 = 1 [default="; required string thisIsNotAField = 1;"];$/;"    f
field2  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^        required string field2 = 2;$/;"   f
field3  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    repeated NestedMessage field3 = 3;$/;"    f
field4  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    optional Enum1 field4 = 4;$/;"    f
field5  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    required Message2.NestedMessage field5 = 5;$/;"   f
field6  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    required .TestPackage.Message2.Enum1 field6 = 6;$/;"  f
field7  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    optional Message2 . NestedMessage field7 = 7;$/;" f
field8  Units/simple-protobuf.d/input.proto /^    repeated int32 field8 = 8 [packed=true];$/;"  f
```